# Деепричастие «ища»

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастия

Является ли ошибкой употребление деепричастия в предложении: «Ища на полке какую-нибудь интересную книгу...»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не вижу никакой ошибки в предложении. "Ища" — [существующее деепричастие](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yINhX.png), и здесь оно вполне уместно.

Comment: А за это нам комиссия не засчитала  балл при написании эссе на этапе Олимпиады. А также за использование деепричастия "беря". Мы подали апелляцию.

Comment: @sisenbaevaelmira это самые обычные деепричастия, не противоречащие никаким правилам и ни в каких словарях не помеченные как просторечные или архаичные. В Нацкорпусе "ища" встречается  2727 раз, "беря" — 1 207. Такие цифры подтверждают абсолютную нормативность этих слов.

Comment: @@sisenbaevaelmira возможно, ошибка была в согласовании деепричастных оборотов? Приведите полностью предложение. «Ища на полке какую-нибудь интересную книгу...» — а дальше что?

Comment: Помню, как я сама впервые прочла его стихи. Ища на полке какую-нибудь интересную книгу, я случайно наткнулась на небольшой сборник стихов Пушкина.

Comment: @sisenbaevaelmira с согласованием всё нормально.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: В словарях нет деепричастий отдельно. Разве где-то формы помечаются так? Эти слова не звучат идеально. Никакие они не самые обычные.

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, интересный вопрос.  С одной стороны, примеров в Нацкорпусе действительно много, причем его использовали известные авторы в разное время.  Слово нужное, но… мне оно не нравится. **Неблагозвучное какое-то.**

«***Ища** на полке какую-нибудь интересную книгу, я случайно наткнулась на небольшой сборник стихов Пушкина»*. Я бы написала: ***Разыскивая** на полке какую-нибудь интересную книгу…*

В приведенных практических примерах мне тоже не попадался вариант с «ища» **в начале предложения.** Какие-то ограничения в использовании деепричастия все-таки возможны. Как говорится, нет дыма без огня…

2. Посмотрела у Грамоты.
   Вопрос № 265198. Существует ли деепричастие несовершенного вида от глагола искать?
   Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Существует **малоупотребительная форма** деепричастия «ища».
3. А что у нас **в Русской корпусной грамматике?**
   [http://rusgram.ru/Деепричастие](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)

**Затруднено образование деепричастий**: от основ настоящего времени V словоизменительного класса глаголов (здесь и далее терминология [Грамматика 1980]) **с чередованием (появлением на стыке основы и суффикса шипящих или сочетания губного с л’),** например, от глаголов брехать, вязать, низать, лизать, мазать, пахать, писать, плясать, резать, слать, сыпать, тесать, чесать;

Под эту статью деепричастие подходит: ***искать – ища***.

4. Итак, вопрос поставлен, а однозначного ответа нет. Подозрений достаточно, но доказательства пока не найдены. Возможно, слово следует отнести **к книжному стилю**, а в разговорной речи оно не очень-то привычно и определенное чувство дискомфорта вызывает. Ведь не зря пользователи задают вопросы о корректности слова.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

Петров испугался, что потеряется и начал оглядываться, **ища** мать в толпе взрослых… [А. Б. Сальников. Петровы в гриппе и вокруг него // «Волга», 2016]

Рабы, что убежали от неволи, В своей судьбе чужой **ища** вины, Все время были чем-то недовольны, Беспомощны, крикливы, голодны. [А. М. Городницкий. Тайны и мифы науки. В поисках истины (2014)]

Он остановился весьма неловко среди комнаты, **ища** и стараясь придумать, что ему сделать. [Н. В. Гоголь. Шинель (1842)]

Comment: Разыскивая — это что-то из полицейского лексикона. Тогда уж 'отыскивая'. // В списке примеров из Грамматики не понял, при чём там 'сыпать'. В слове 'сыпя' нет ни шипящего на стыке, ни 'л'. // Тем не менее это всё равно не аргумент для отъятия балла. Во-первых, практика позволяет, во-вторых, вы сами говорили, что сорокалетняя Грамматика не так уж актуальна. В БТС "ища" указано без каких-либо ремарок.

Comment: Разыскивают вроде бы только кого-то. Вроде бы "сыпя" нормально. Отнёс бы "ища", наоборот, к разговорному стилю. Книжный не для неблагозвучного.

Comment: @Nektoid
Разыскивая – нельзя?  А мне  кажется, что выбор зависит от ситуации, надо просто проверить значения приставок.  Я ничего не утверждаю определенно, но не считаю стилистически корректным приведенное предложение. Пока у меня такие доводы: книжный стиль предложения; реальные ограничения в образовании деепричастий, указанные в Грамматике;  мнение Грамоты (возможно, там шла речь именно о разговорном стиле, для которого слово нехарактерно). Да и баллы зря снижать не будут, не так ли? :))

Comment: @oleedd  Книжную речь мы воспринимаем зрительно, возможно, там оно более уместно. А благозвучие важно для разговорного стиля.  Форма слова странная, по ней (при наличии чередования) не сразу определишь, что это за деепричастие. На полке книги, наверное, дейтвительно отыскивают, это книжные любители разыкивают редкости в своей области.

Comment: @Sharon я не сказал "нельзя". Я сказал, что на данный момент слово "разыскивая" стало ассоциироваться с оперативно-розыскными мероприятиями. Так бывает, что какое-то изначально нейтральное слово в какой-то исторический период "приватизируется" некоей коннотацией. // Про "сыпя" вы не пояснили.

Comment: Сыпать – сыплю, сыплет. Там обязательное Л, нужно тогда использовать форму сыпля (сыпя –запрещена).

Comment: Книжная речь – та, к которой не придерёшься, но порой она слишком интеллигентная. А что насчёт "беря"? Оно ещё хуже. Балл, как сказано, не за одно деепричастие сняли. Отыскивают пропавшее, а не что-нибудь новое (как здесь).

Comment: Из грамматики: (2) Затруднено образование деепричастий от неслоговой основы настоящего времени (см. Основы глагола), например: от глаголов I спряжения: врать, ждать, лгать, жрать, рвать, ржать, ткать, мереть, переть, жать, мять, вить, пить, шить и нек. др.;  Наверное, брать –  беру – беря им не нравится, появляется беглый гласный, ударение на последнем слоге, слово плохо узнается в речи.

Comment: @Sharon http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=273600

Comment: Сыплет черемуха снегом, Зелень в цвету и росе...Вот это правильная речь, а пропуск Л похоже на просторечие, в школе это ошибкой считалось. Это историческое чередование  п/пл, б/бл, м/мл перед определенными гласными,  и никто эту норму не отменял. "Губные согласные б, п, в, м также не могли быть мягкими и в положении перед * j , выделяя вставочный согласный l ' , образовывали сочетания бл', вл', пл', м/мл ': * korabj ь > корабль; * zemja > земл?а; * lowja > ловля; *.https://studopedia.ru/16_111918_izmeneniya-praslavyanskogo-perioda-svyazannie-s-deystviem-zakona-slogovogo-singarmonizma.html

Comment: @Sharon "По рельсам поезд сыпет, / под рельсой шпалы сыпятся..." (Маяковский); "Как будто царь неизмеримо щедрый / Алмазов белых сыпет бездне клад" (Гумилёв); "...Наподобье снега / Что-то в чашку сыпет" (Юнна Мориц).

Comment: Ну это поэты, у них все не как у людей. А вообще говоря, просторечие оказывает значительное влияние на нашу речь, так что приходится все это нормировать. Образованных и грамотных людей мало, а прочих – не счесть.  Так что теперь можно, словарь РАН разрешил: говорите "сыпет и сыпя".

Comment: @Sharon ага, то есть как мои поэты — так "не всё как у людей", а как самой Есенина цитировать — так всё норм. Яяясно :)

Comment: Так ваши-то все   – футуристы и акмеисты, а Есенин  – наш чистый родник.